# How to log table and column name in case DB error in spring/JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

in a single service, I'm persisting a whole hierarchy of objects to Postgresql with Spring Data/JPA/Hibernate.

While persisting one of the instances, DB raises an error that data is too long for a given column definition:

```
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(5)
```

Neither PG nor Spring logs table/entity name nor column name.

The only hint in logs is the above message and stack trace pointing to the service method.

Of course, I can tediously analyze the data, and table definitions and came up with quite a narrow list of suspicious points however I believe there must be a better solution, a way to configure PG or Spring/JPA to log that for me.

Ofc I don't want to change globally the logging level for Spring Data or Hibernate to DEBUG or TRACE. That would clutter and explode my logs.

I just need that simple information in case the INSERT/UPDATE fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it does not appear that there is a way to set Spring or Postgresql to make this info available.

The issue is Postgresql. It does not log (or return to the client) the table/column which is the cause of the error.

If the [client_min_messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) and [log_min_messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-MESSAGES) are set to the highest level, ie DEBUG5:

```
set log_min_messages = 'DEBUG5';
set client_min_messages = 'DEBUG5';
insert into persons (name, title) values ('too long', 'Joe bloggs')
```

This returns the following to the pgadmin client:

```
DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0

ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(4)
SQL state: 22001
```

And logs the following:

```
2023-03-17 11:15:57,995: ERROR  pgadmin:    Failed to execute query (execute_async) for the server #1 - CONN:8508187(Query-id: 916721):
Error Message:DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0

ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(4)
SQL state: 22001
```

What I suggest is that you use `javax.validation.constraints.Size` or `jakarta.validation.constraints.Size` (for spring-boot 3.x / jdk17+) available with `spring-boot-starter-validation`:

```
@Column(name = "title", length=4)
@Size(max = 4)
private String title;
```

This will provide much better info to work with:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.example.demo.persistence.Person] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 0 and 4', propertyPath=title, rootBeanClass=class com.example.demo.persistence.Person, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
```

]

For completeness this is a snippet of spring trace level log:

```
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Parse(stmt=null,query="BEGIN",oids={})
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Bind(stmt=null,portal=null)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Execute(portal=null,limit=0)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Parse(stmt=null,query="insert into persons (id, name, title) values (default, $1, $2)
1043})       
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Bind(stmt=null,portal=null,$1=<'joe bloggs'>,type=VARCHAR,$2=<'too long'>,type=VARCHAR)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Describe(portal=null)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Execute(portal=null,limit=0)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Sync
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE ParseComplete [null]
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE BindComplete [unnamed]
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE CommandStatus(BEGIN)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE ParseComplete [null]
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE ErrorMessage(ERROR: value too long for type character varying(4))
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE ReadyForQuery(E)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE marking setPortalDescribed(false) for query insert into persons (id, name, title) values (default, ?, ?)
             
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE marking setPortalDescribed(false) for query SYNC
 WARN 16580  o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22001
ERROR 16580  o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: value too long for type character varying(4)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :   simple execute, handler=org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection$TransactionCommandHandler@1e79986b, maxRows=0, fetchSize=0, flags=22
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Parse(stmt=S_1,query="ROLLBACK",oids={})
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Bind(stmt=S_1,portal=null)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Execute(portal=null,limit=1)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Sync
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE ParseComplete [S_1]
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE BindComplete [unnamed]
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE CommandStatus(ROLLBACK)
TRACE 16580  o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  <=BE ReadyForQuery(I)
```

Comment: Hi,

thanks for your answer. For me it is crucial that the problem is in PG so it is hard to mitigate it in Spring.

BTW in spring-boot 3.x @Max is moved to package `jakarta.validation.constraints.Size`

Comment: yes, 3.x uses jdk17 - updated answer

Comment: I'll issue Feature Request to PG, who nows, maybe they will fix that :)